# Booting with nvidia drivers only without splash

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, plymouth

When booting up my laptop (with a dedicated nvidia GPU inside) I found that very often it will not boot into the desktop -- for example when the HDMI monitor is hooked up. Sometimes even without anything attached it will not boot up.

When it stops I can see the gpu-manager was hung for 120s.

I poked around and found that by removing the `splash` from the grub cmd line everything works as it should.

But can someone tell me, why?

Thanks

P.S. Removing the nvidia drivers helps too, but then I will not have a gaming laptop.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It is a Kubuntu 21.10

Answer (score 0):

From this resource: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

**Permanently Add a Kernel Boot Parameter**

1. Log in to the system and start a terminal (window/Applications->Accessories->Terminal).
2. In the terminal window at the $ prompt, enter the command:
   `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. Enter your password when prompted by [sudo].
4. In the editor window, use the arrow keys to move the cursor to the line beginning with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` then edit that line, and suppress `splash` from the text inside the double-quotes (normally `"quiet splash"`.)
5. Click the Save button, then close the editor window.
6. In the terminal window at the $ prompt, enter the command: `sudo update-grub`
7. Restart the system.

Note: The parameter(s) you've added to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line are persistent, and will be in effect for every subsequent boot session (unless you remove them by repeating the procedure above).